# No PHP requests through Tor/Privoxy

Tags: php, tor

I´m trying to connect to different websites via PHP through Tor/Privoxy. The PHP scripts and Tor/Privoxy run on the same server.

Privoxy is configured as follows

```
forward-socks4a / 127.0.0.1:9050 .
forward-socks5 / 127.0.0.1:9050 .
confdir /etc/privoxy
logdir /var/log/privoxy
logfile logfile
actionsfile match-all.action
actionsfile default.action
actionsfile user.action
filterfile default.filter
debug   32
debug   128
debug   1024
debug   4096
debug   8192
user-manual /usr/share/doc/privoxy/user-manual
listen-address  127.0.0.1:8118
toggle  1
enable-remote-toggle 0
enable-edit-actions 0
enable-remote-http-toggle 0
buffer-limit 4096
```

Tors configuration

```
SocksPort 9050
SocksPolicy accept 127.0.0.1
SocksPolicy reject *
Log warn syslog
RunAsDaemon 1
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
```

I´m trying to connect using a script I found at [PHP SSL stream_socket_client won't use created $context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691573/php-ssl-stream-socket-client-wont-use-created-context) which I modified slightly to fit my needs

```
<?php

$desthost = "derdualstudent.de";
$port     = 80;
$conflag  = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT;

try
{
    $socket = stream_socket_client( "tcp://127.0.0.1:8118", $errno, $errstr, 15, $conflag );

    fwrite( $socket, pack( "C3", 0x05, 0x00, 0x00 ) );
    $server_status = fread( $socket, 2048 );
    if ( $server_status == pack( "C2", 0x05, 0x00 ) )
    {
        // Connection succeeded
    }
    else
    {
        die( "SOCKS Server does not support this version and/or authentication method of SOCKS.\r\n" );
    }

    fwrite( $socket, pack( "C5", 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, strlen( $desthost ) ) . $desthost . pack( "n", $port ) );
    $server_buffer = fread( $socket, 10 );

    if ( ord( $server_buffer[0] ) == 5 && ord( $server_buffer[1] ) == 0 && ord( $server_buffer[2] ) == 0 )
    {
        // Connection succeeded
    }
    else
    {
        die( "The SOCKS server failed to connect to the specificed host and port. ( " . $desthost . ":" . $port . " )\r\n" );
    }

    stream_socket_enable_crypto( $socket, TRUE, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv23_CLIENT );
}
catch ( Exception $e )
{
    die( $e->getMessage() );
}

if ( $socket === FALSE )
{
    die( "bad socket" );
}

fwrite( $socket, "GET /\n" );
echo fread( $socket, 10255 );

?>
```

The script drops dead with "SOCKS Server does not support this version and/or authentication method of SOCKS.". I experimented with the authentication (0x00 and 0x01 both don´t work).

There is also a script a colleague of me wrote on the same server

```
<?php
$vOpts = array('http'=>array(
 'method'=>"GET",
 'request_fulluri'=>TRUE,
 'proxy'=>'tcp://localhost:8118',
 'header'=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de-DE; rv:1.8) Gecko/20051111 Firefox/16.0\r\n"."Accept-language: de\r\n"."\r\n"
));
$vContext = stream_context_create($vOpts);
$vFile = file_get_contents("http://www.derdualstudent.de?tor=1",FALSE,$vContext);
?>
```

This produces the error

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.derdualstudent.de?tor=1): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 503 Forwarding failure
 in /home/pi/php_scripts/temp.php on line 9
```

The logs of Tor and Privoxy contain no helpful informations.